# Examples of CFTs

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory

Are there any examples of conformal field theories in 3 or more dimensions that are not free or supersymmetric and can be described by a Lagrangian?

Comment: CFTs are typically (perhaps always, if non-supersymmetric) strongly coupled and so do not admit Lagrangian formulations.

Comment: Here's an example of a 5d CFT with a simple, non-supersymmetric Lagrangian: https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.1094

Comment: 3d Ising or equivalently the $\phi^4$ model in 3d gives a CFT with a Lagrangian desciption. One can also enlarge this to long range models or vector valued fields to get a lot more examples.

Comment: There are lots of examples of UV Lagrangians that flow to non-trivial CFTs in the IR, for example the 3d Ising CFT as mentioned by Abdelmalek Abdesselam. However, unless you put these on a computer, they are not very useful for computing anything quantitative about the CFT unless the theory is perturbative along the entire flow. A classical example of this are the Wilson-Fisher fixed points in $4-\epsilon$ dimensions.